# Is there a cross-browser way to ignore 401 errors triggered by XHRs?

Tags: javascript, http, http-digest

Attempting to keep as pure of a REST approach as possible, I decided that the application **would** be the API - down to the last bit.

Unfortunately, I have reached one stumbling block. After writing a Digest authentication handler in PHP, I found myself unable to make the experience as friendly for users in web browsers as an form-based authentication method would be.

The reason for this is that even though I can simulate a Digest authentication response through Javascript, using username and password from a HTML form (I can give the `nonce` values to the script safely, due to the way they are generated), on failure, the browser still shows the standard, ugly authentication prompt.

Is there any way around this? An earlier question references `mozBackgroundRequest`, but that seems hardly cross-browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a request with AJAX first, to make sure the authentication details provided work.

If they do, do what you have been doing. If they don't, tell the user about it in your own, nicer way...

**EDIT**

If you control the auth routine in PHP (and if auth fails, presumably doing `header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');` etc) you can just... not do it. Instead, respond with a normal 200 OK but put a string in the body that you can look for in `ajax.responseText` (like 'authFailed' or something).

You can just add a header (or a cookie, or something) to the AJAX requests that are not present in normal browser requests, to allow you to distinguish between the AJAX auth checks and a normal, authenticated session.

The exact mechanics are a little fuzzy in my head at the moment (it's been a long day) but I am sure it could be done using that method.

Comment: Well, that is what I am currently doing. The problem is that the prompt dialog seems to be shown regardless - unless you mean I write some sort of other method of verifying data? That might be an option, albeit a messy one.

Comment: Nope, I meant just check for a 401 in the `responseCode` - I thought this would silently fail without showing a prompt, but I just tried it and it doesn't. Actually, I just had an idea from reading another post, see my edit in a minute or two...

Comment: Just tested - I think that that seems to be the neatest solution, until hopefully browser vendors make a better way available. I ran into a different problem - that the authentication request I made wouldn't be "remembered" - but that's for another question, and one that will likely remain unsolved...

Comment: You could remember something with Cookies, maybe?

Comment: Yes, but that'd pretty much defeat the purpose of using HTTP Digest authentication instead of just rolling my own digest-based authentication (presumably powered by Javascript)

Comment: Fair comment, never thought of it like that!